# Matlab save() function not saving data

Tags: matlab, save, load

**EDIT:** It turns out that the saving location wasn't large enough to hold the file. For later readers, if save() doesn't return an error, but saves an empty file it's possibly a saving directory that's too small.

I have a script with which I create a matlab struct. which i name `imageStruct`.

```
> >> imageStruct
> 
> imageStruct = 
> 
>   1×4746 struct array with fields:
> 
>     objectNumber
>     title
>     principalOrFirstMaker
>     productionPlaces
>     date
>     orginalCollection
>     webLink
```

I can save this variable from my Workspace by using:

```
save('imageStruct.mat','imageStruct')
```

and I can also load it into my Workspace again:

```
> clc;
> load('imageStruct.mat')
>> length(imageStruct)
ans =
    4746
```

So far so good. Next, I add data to `imageStruct`, which increased it to a 1 x 11496 struct array.

```
>>metData = readtable('meta_data_metropolitan_paintings.txt','FileEncoding','UTF-8','Delimiter','\t');

>>for i = 1:length(metData.Obj_num)
    disp(i)
    imageStruct(length(imageStruct)+1).objectNumber = char(metData.var1(i));
    imageStruct(length(imageStruct)).title = metData.var2(i);
    imageStruct(length(imageStruct)).productionPlaces = metData.var3;
    imageStruct(length(imageStruct)).medium = metData.var4(i); 
    imageStruct(length(imageStruct)).date = metData.var5(i);
    imageStruct(length(imageStruct)).principalOrFirstMaker = metData.var6(i);
    imageStruct(length(imageStruct)).orginalCollection = metData.var7(i);
    imageStruct(length(imageStruct)).webLink = metData.var8(i);
end 


>>imageStruct

imageStruct = 

  1×11496 struct array with fields:

objectNumber
title
principalOrFirstMaker
productionPlaces
date
orginalCollection
webLink
medium
```

If i than use `save('imageStruct.mat','imageStruct')` again, it will not save data. A file named 'imageStruct.mat' will be created, but it is empty. I can use imageStruct normally, and there doesn't seem to be any difference between the original and the newly created version, besides the added data.

I though it might have been due to size limitations, but I tried to duplicate the original structure a few times until it was 1 x 20000, and it saved just fine.

Comment: This should not happen. Either you are doing something else wrong, or your MATLAB installation is bad/broken. Its very likely to be the first one (no offense). But I can save Gb in a single .mat that should not be a problem.

Comment: @AnderBiguri. No offense taken. Besides the actions listed in the post, I take no other actions for as far as I know. To rule out the broken installation; is it possible that save()/load() consistently works on the orginal imagestruct, but consistently fails on the updated version?

Comment: Do you have enough disk space to save the new file?

Comment: @MitchellvanZuylen save should work with absolutely *anything*!

Comment: And, if save should encouter any problem during execution, it will always throw a warning or an error. If it remains silent and yet writes an empty file this is very strange. I've never encountered it. Can you test it on another computer / another Matlab version?

Comment: @matlabgui That's not the problem, i have about a TB left, and I appear to be able to save larger structs without problems.

Comment: @matlabgui. Turns out it was the problem after all, in a way. I didn't realize the working directory was on a network. As a result i only had about 10GB instead of the TB on my SSD. Moved directory and it now works.

Comment: @MitchellvanZuylen - Good to hear you've sorted it.   I have a vague memory of something similar happening with a network file many years ago - empty file but no warning/error from save...